# Математика для компьютерного зрения?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, opencv

Какие разделы математики нужны для работы с библиотеками компьютерного зрения типа opencv и др., работа с видео(распознание объектов, обнаружение слежение  за объектом, и тд.)
Если можно то литературу по этим разделам математики потому как моя математика ограничивается школьным курсом.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Не ответ на ваш вопрос, но: рекомендую почитать вопросы по метке [tag:opencv-faq]

Comment: Не задавал бы вопрос не почитав.

Comment: Opencv, не сложный, достаточно понимать алгоритмы, документация есть. А в зависимости от того что ты хочешь с его помощью делать, тебе уже будут нужны знания что бы писать свои алгоритмы. Мне в свое время пригодилась векторная геометрия.

Answer (score 1):

На вопрос трудно ответить однозначно, поскольку в той или иной мере затрагиваются наверное все разделы алгебры, геометрии и даже физики. Иногда и биологии, если стоит специфическая задача распознавания. И точно также многих иных областей науки. Не хватит и нескольких жизней, чтобы ознакомиться со всем набором знаний, который может потенциально пригодиться. По сему, решать задачи от обратного по меньшей мере бессмысленно.

Ну представьте, что нужно построить дом. Известны необходимые инструменты для строительства. Если начать изучать по каждому из них историю возникновения, теорию в деталях, как он устроен и используется, то непосредственно к строительству можно будет перейти к закату собственной жизни. Во избежание этого необходимо уметь выделять только то, что нужно для решения специфической задачи. Например, тантрическая практика владения молотком вряд ли поможет в строительстве дома, а вот практический навык забивания гвоздей - вполне.

Постарайтесь детализировать свой вопрос путём описания конкретной практической задачи. Это поможет существенно сузить область необходимых для её реализации знаний.

Comment: Задача состоит в том что-бы в видео потоке 1) обнаружить движение объекта 2) классифицировать объект 3) следить за перемещением объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала дифференциальное и интегральное исчисления, преобразование Фурье, линейная алгебра, теория вероятности и статистика.

В основе компьютерного зрения лежит обработка изображений. Изображение можно рассматривать как дискретную функцию двух переменных или как двумерный сигнал. Соответсвенно нужно знать что такое частная производная, преобразование Фурье и свертка.

Для обнаружения и распознавания объектов есть много алгоритмов, большинство из которых сводятся к теории вероятности и статистике. Для слежения часто используется фильтр Калмана, который тоже основан на теории вероятности.

Ну и без матриц никуда не денешься, так что линейная алгебра совершенно необходима.

Answer (score 0):

Фактически в современных библиотеках (OpenCV, DLIB и пр.) базовые алгоритмы редко выходят за пределы линейной алгебры и тригонометрии с различными спецглавами, важно понимание математической модели Pinhole Camera. 
Классическим фолиантом на эту тему считается труд [Hartley и Zissermann](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/)
Также на сайте [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/books.html) найдете полный список книг на разные тематики и области применения.